# Bluetooth packet capture on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use the technic described [here](https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2014/02/07/bluetooth-packet-capture-on-android-4-4/) to capture the Bluetooth paquets exchanged between my Android phone and a device (a very simple device).

I can capture a lot of scanning and the pairing between the two devices, but I can't see any of the later exchanges, only the scanning.
Moreover, just after the pairing there is a huge gap in the time, and other gaps later when I think data are exchanged between the device.
For exemple, the timeline is in this form:

- 0-8s: scanning (`LE Set Scan`)
- 8-15s: pairing
- 80-120s: scanning
- 180-200s:scanning

I'm sure that the gaps correspond with data exchanges, but I don't know why I can't see the paquets.

I've tried simple file exchange between the phone and a computer, and I've been able to see the paquets containing the file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the BLE and you are sniff the air log. According to your description, you can scan the advertisement(and scan) and the pair procedure(I assume after the pair you can see nothing).
Did you entered the LTK(long term key)? it is just something like the link key in the classic Bluetooth, with out this you can not decrypt the  encrypted packages. The best method to observer the log would be check the btsnoop.log.
You said you can see the paquets between PC and your mobile phone, should be you are using classic Bluetooth actually? or you did not pairing?

Comment: It's not BLE, but BT classic with legacy PIN (so I'm not even sure it's BT4). I use the file `btsnoop_hci.log`. I did not enter the LTK: I wasn't aware I could do that, and I thought it was unnecessary because I thought that the capture was done after the deciphering of the paquets done by the controller.

Comment: If it was not BLE, then you do not need the LTK. The file btsnoop_hci.log does not need the link key since it was the local stack's log. So you can paste your btsnoop log snap to see what happen.